# How to make a button to stay on the main screen in a corner?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to make a application which will consists of a button.
This button will be added in the corner of the phone display and will never disappear.(If I open a certain application the button should be there).

For example : the assistant touch in iOS

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please clarify... which corner? on home screen of the phone? you need tile for your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to have an always available button on the main screen of your phone that is persistent in whatever you do.

You cannot add buttons outside your application to the OS directly, but you can add tiles for your application to launch from.

Comment: Tiles are your application icons that people can pin to their start screen. Once you install the application you can tap and hold the icon to get a dialog box that says "pin to start".

Answer (score 0):

It's quite vague, but you can try this.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="100"> </RowDefinition> <!-- use this to put your button -->
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Button Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

</Grid>
```